# Как написать скрипт для автоотправки сообщения в группу для телеграмм-канала?

Tags: javascript, python, telegram

Недавно наткнулся на аккаунт(не бот), который отправил рекламу. Я ему написал и мне пришел авто ответ, хотя это был не бот. Все поиски в интернете приводят именно к созданию бота. Может кто в курсе, как сделать скрипт, который будет отправлять сообщение именно от моего аккаунта. Желательно на JS или Python

Comment: Это бот... Вам нужно сделать бота...

Comment: У бота ник всегда оканчивается на _bot, в том случае такого не было

Comment: в таком случае изучите `MTProto API` используется в том же `pyrogram` на Python

Answer (score 2):

##### Ответ переведён с <kbd>[enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63272437/how-can-i-send-a-message-to-someone-with-telegram-api-using-my-own-account)</kbd>

---

Telegram имеет подробный и документированный [общедоступный API](https://core.telegram.org/api).

Вот сокращённые важные понятия оттуда:

- API не ограничен ботами, это просто особый тип пользователей;
- в API есть методы [`getMessages`](https://core.telegram.org/methods) и [`sendMessage`](https://core.telegram.org/methods), это должно быть то, что вам нужно
- для вызова API Telegram рекомендует использовать специальную библиотеку [`TDLib`](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/getting-started), доступную для нескольких языков программирования
- На GitHub доступно [несколько примеров](https://github.com/tdlib/td/blob/master/example/README.md#tdlib-usage-and-build-examples)

Они рекомендуют:

> Если вы используете современный `Python ≥ 3.6`, взгляните на [`python-telegram`](https://github.com/alexander-akhmetov/python-telegram).

Там вы найдете инструкции по использованию библиотеки, а в папке с примерами вы можете найти скрипт для отправки сообщения.

Я скопирую его здесь для полноты картины:

```
import logging
import argparse

from utils import setup_logging
from telegram.client import Telegram

"""
Sends a message to a chat
Usage:
    python examples/send_message.py api_id api_hash phone chat_id text
"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup_logging(level=logging.INFO)

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('api_id', help='API id')  # https://my.telegram.org/apps
    parser.add_argument('api_hash', help='API hash')
    parser.add_argument('phone', help='Phone')
    parser.add_argument('chat_id', help='Chat id', type=int)
    parser.add_argument('text', help='Message text')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    tg = Telegram(
        api_id=args.api_id,
        api_hash=args.api_hash,
        phone=args.phone,
        database_encryption_key='changeme1234',
    )
    # you must call login method before others
    tg.login()

    # if this is the first run, library needs to preload all chats
    # otherwise the message will not be sent
    result = tg.get_chats()

    # `tdlib` is asynchronous, so `python-telegram` always returns you an `AsyncResult` object.
    # You can wait for a result with the blocking `wait` method.
    result.wait()

    if result.error:
        print(f'get chats error: {result.error_info}')
    else:
        print(f'chats: {result.update}')

    result = tg.send_message(
        chat_id=args.chat_id,
        text=args.text,
    )

    result.wait()
    if result.error:
        print(f'send message error: {result.error_info}')
    else:
        print(f'message has been sent: {result.update}')
```

Конечно, вам нужно изучить документацию, чтобы узнать, что представляют собой все эти переменные или идентификаторы, но это всё равно должно вам помочь.

---

**Мой комментарий:** таким образом, вы сможете отправлять сообщения из своей учётной записи, используя `Python`.